# YamlDotNet what is the object equivalent?

Tags: yaml, yamldotnet

I have 2 setups:

## 1

```
- container:
  - ParamA
  - ParamB
  - ParamC
```

## 2

```
- container:
  ParamA: X
  ParamB: Y
  ParamC: Z
```

In scenario 1 it seems to be deserialized into a class container with ParamA, ParamB, and ParamC.

```
public class Container
{
    public string ParamA { get; set;}
    public string ParamB { get; set;}
    public string ParamC { get; set;}
}
```

But in Scenario 2 (note there's no '-' and it has a key/value set up with the key being anything) how would this be represented as an object?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Dictionary does the trick. Makes sense, it's a key-value pair of n amount.

Answer (score 0):

In scenario 1, you have a sequence of one element, in which that element is a mapping with a single scalar key, whose value is itself a sequence of three scalars. A possible mapping to objects would be a `List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>`.

In scenario 2, the difference is that the value of the first key is a mapping instead of a list. A possible maping would be `List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>`. Another mapping would be `List<Dictionary<string, Container>>`.